# Oracle In Clause not working when using Parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Pesky SSRS report Problem where in the main query of my report has a condition  that can have more than 1000 choices and when user selects all it will fail as my backend database is Oracle.  I have done some research  and found a solution that would work.

Solution is

re-writing the in clause  something like this

```
(1,ColumnName) in ((1,Searchitem1),(1,SearchItem2))
```

this will work however when I do this

```
(1,ColumnName) in ((1,:assignedValue))
```

and pass just one value it works. But when I pass more than one value it fails  and gives me ORA-01722: Invalid number error

I have tried multiple combination of the same in clause but nothing is working

any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: your `:assignedValue` is a comma-separated list of numbers, and Oracle tries to parse it as a single number.

Passing multiple values as a single value for an `IN` query is (almost) never a good idea - either you have to use string concatenation (prone to SQL injection and terrible performance), or you have to have a fixed number of arguments to `IN` (which generally is not what you want).

I'd suggest you

- `INSERT` your search items into a temporary table
- use a `JOIN` with this search table in your `SELECT`

Comment: I cant do the Temp Table  as it will be running from the SSRS report and multiple users can access this  report at the same time.  I have thought of that option before.

Comment: A temporary table is specific to a given database session. Unless your SSRS report uses connection pooling, it should work.